# Multiple payment gateways/processor options for multiple Vendors

Tags: wordpress

I am using a WordPress plugin to create a multi-vendor marketplace.  However, I would like the Vendors to be able to configure any payment gateway of their choosing (eg: PayPal, Authorize.net, etc) into their store for payment processing.

Thanks

Comment: What plug-in are you using?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/